# Rounding Floating Point Number To two Decimal Places in C++

Tags: c++

After Rounding to two decimal places, i alwayse get the same value

```
float TestT =round(t*100)/100;
```

[image]

i would like to round it and fix it to two decimal places: 0.009999 -> 0.01

Comment: Please note that often, `float` numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary...

Comment: In which case a `float`, just like an `int` is the wrong type for this job. If you need exact 2 decimal places, then one way is to use an integral type, and insert the decimal point at the point of presentation. Or use a *decimal* type from an appropriate library. Boost has one, for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this in 2 steps:-

Step1:- transform your float value to string and use the inbuilt QString feature to perform the rounding for you

Eg:-

1. @QString::number( 99.48, 'f', 2);
2. In your case:- QString TestS =QString::number( t, 'f', 2);

Step2:- transform your rounded string value to float
Eg:-

1. in your case :- float TestT= TestS.toFloat()

More info about this here is some links:-
QString":http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#number-2 may help you.

Comment: This has no advantage over the solution of OP, which is right. What is wrong is the assumption that 0.01 can be represented exactly as a `float`: it cannot.